# How to have an angularJS directive on a page called via ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rendering, directive

I have the following html (which can be accessed directly or called via ajax):

```
<section id="content" ng-controller="setTreeDataCtrl" get-subthemes>
<dl ng-repeat="subtheme in allSubthemes">
    <dt>{{subtheme.Title}}</dt>
</dl>
```

Then I'm using the following directive:

```
myApp.directive('getSubthemes', function() {
return function($scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.allSubthemes = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.data.Themes, function(value, key) {
        angular.forEach(value.SubThemes, function(value2, key2) {
            $scope.allSubthemes.push({
                'ThemeTitle': value.Title,
                'ThemeUrlSlug': value.UrlSlug,
                'Title': value2.Title,
                'UrlSlug': value2.UrlSlug
            });
        });
    });
}
});
```

$scope.allSubthemes seems ok, but the dl's don't get rendered.
I can see for a second everything rendered properly and then it get's back to {{subtheme.Title}}, almost like it's being "unrendered"... any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Demo jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HMp3a/

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this so we can debug quicker.

Comment: Here you have: http://jsfiddle.net/HMp3a/

Comment: Well I don't know about your real code, but the fiddle did not have angularjs loaded. [Here's the fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMp3a/3/)

Comment: missing the ng-app was a mistake in my jsfiddle. Although yours jsfiddle works, mine like I said, shows up the correct rendering for a second and ends up showing {{subtheme.Title}} not rendered. Any other idea of what may be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

rGil fixed the jsFiddle. It was missing a `ng-app="pddc"` declaration on an element so Angular did not know where to begin its magic.

I'd like to mention another way to render to the data in question. I suggest using an `ng-repeat` within an `ng-repeat`. See my forked & updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Kpm/3/). You can actually refer to the parent theme within the `ng-repeat` of the subtheme, so you don't have to copy values from the parent theme into each subtheme (which effectively eliminates the need for the directive in this example).

Another reason to use a nested `ng-repeat` is because of async issues that could come up when pulling data from a web service asynchronously. What could happen is when the directive executes, it may not have any data to loop through and populate because the data hasn't arrived yet.

If you use two ng-repeats, Angular will watch the `$scope.data` and re-run the ng-repeats when the data arrives. I've added a 500 ms delay to setting the data in my example to simulate web service latency and you'll see that even with the "latency", the data eventually renders.

There are two other ways around the async issue:

1. Use [scope.$watch()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) in your directive, to watch for the data manually, or
2. Use the "resolve" functionality from Angular's [routing feature](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider#when) to make sure the data is retrieved prior to controller execution.

While these alternative methods work, I think both are more complicated then just using two ng-repeats.

Comment: I was missing the ng-app when I did the jsfiddle, but I had it in my code.
The nested ng-repeat seems like a good solution, but I would like to have the dl's next to each other, having multiple containers is a problem in my scenario.
I'm not using routing in my app so I would prefer another solution. Is it possible to use the nested ng-repeat keeping the same container for all dl's?
If not, how can I do it with $watch?
What bothers me is that I can see the correct rendering for half a second but it ends up showing {{subtheme.Title}} without rendering. Do you have any idea of what might be?

Comment: Also with the nested ng-repeat the order wouldn't be correct since it's ordering only for each theme individually and I want all subthemes ordered without depending on their parent (theme).